# Excel : Display hours over 24 when using TIME()

Tags: excel

I found many posts which say how to display hours if it exceeds 24. But in my case it doesn't work.

I have 3 cells which contain hours, minutes, seconds. In the fourth cell I used formula `=TIME(E4,F4,G4)` where E4 contains hours, F4 contains minutes and G4 contains seconds. I formatted the cell using

> Format Cells --> Number --> Custom --> [hh]:mm:ss

. But still am not getting the correct value in the cell.

```
hours | minutes |   seconds |   Time
81    | 22      |   27.045  |   09:22:27

Expected value as Time is "81:22:27"
```

Is there any other formatting required?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Time](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/time-function-HP010342955.aspx) function takes the remainder for each argument.  The remainder of 81/24 is 9, which is why it is showing 9 hours.  You would need to add the rest back in, like so:

```
=TIME(,F4,G4)+E4/24
```

Comment: =E4/24 + TIME(0,F4,G4)

Comment: yeah, that is a bit more efficient, only need to access E4 once, I'll update answer, thank you for tip!

Comment: +1 for explaining why TIME function was not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since your "expected value" is `81:22:27`, you could just construct the time as a concatenation of the respective values:

```
=RIGHT("0"&INT(E4),2)&":"&RIGHT("0"&INT(F4),2)&":"&RIGHT("0"&INT(G4),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Even this works. The other answer has been accepted since it's simpler and uses TIME. No offence. :)

Comment: @1234: The use of `RIGHT("0"&..,2)` is to ensure a 2-digit output of the form `hh:mm:ss`, but is not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate your time differently - but format the result as [h]:mm:ss

If Hours, Minutes, Secs are in A1, A2, A3

Then in A4 use formula =DATE(0,1,A1/24)+TIME(A1,B1,C1)

Format A4 as [h]:mm:ss and that will do it!